# I want to start animation at specific duration Time on MotionLayout in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-motionlayout

I have one animation on MotionLayout. I want to control the location of object . For example, let's say the transition duration is 10 seconds. When the app starts I want to start the animation from 7. seconds. How can I do in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this

```java
ml.progress = 0.7
ml.transitionToEnd()
```